# Polymath under-reports sites

Tags: discussion, winter-bash-2016

The Polymath hat is described thus:

> post at least one well-received answer on three different sites during Winter Bash (not including Stack Overflow)

I just earned it on two sites:

[image: screen shot]

How did I earn a hat requiring activity on three sites on only two of those sites?

The third site, and the first site on which I earned any Winterbash-related reputation, is Meta.SE, which isn't listed.

(Silver lining: I now have a better idea what "well-received" means.)

Comment: Caching. ;) It appears you've earned it on Writers & here now too.

Comment: Huh, weird.  I mean, I thought caching at first, but MSE was the *first* relevant site and not included, so that threw me.  I've just gotten two more notifications.

Answer (score 3):

I still don't know why the timing was that way, but I've now received two more notifications:

[image: screen shot]

The order in which I received upvotes on new posts was: MSE (not long after Winterbash started), Writers (several hours ago), and Workplace and Worldbuilding within the last hour.

(I wasn't expecting or "going for" this hat, figuring it would require a lot more votes, so I wasn't keeping careful track of timing.  But hey, surprise headwear!)

Comment: Without knowing anything about how this was implemented, I'd wager these are run per-site (while, of course, looking at your record on other sites) - which means you'll eventually earn them on all qualifying sites, but only when the badge task runs there. Given there are very few cross-site badges, a network-global task to award them would probably be more complicated than worthwhile.